# Formatting currency in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, formatting

In my current project, I am storing a currency value as an `int` which represents the number of cents. However, when the user inputs this value in a text field, they will most likely expect to enter it as a decimal value. Also, I would like to prepend a dollar sign if the user doesn't enter it manually. How can I leverage a `JFormattedTextField` to do much of this work for me? Or is there other solutions using pre-existing Swing components so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel by coding this all by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NumberFormat` is also suited to format a currency (see [`NumberFormat#getCurrencyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28java.util.Locale%29)). And since you need a `Format` for the `JFormattedTextField` I would start there.

You can configure the `NumberFormat` to allow decimal values, and convert it later on in your code to an `int` without problems

Comment: If I use this solution, what kind of `Object` is returned by `JFormattedTextField.getValue()`?

Comment: If you use a `NumberFormat`, it will return a `Number`

Comment: Is there any way to know the concrete class, other than using the `instanceof` operator? It would be nice to be able to cast to `Double` and use auto-unboxing in this situation. I also use other `JFormattedTextField`s for integer input, so casting to an `Integer` for those would be great, too!

Comment: There is no need for an instance of. Since you set the `Format` yourself, you know what the return type will be (the return type of the `parse` method of the `Format`). So if you want a `Double`, you use a `Format` which returns a double. But not sure what the problem is of doing `Number#doubleValue()`

Comment: The problem is a PEBKAC error: not looking closely enough at the APIs =p

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to consider Joda Money library -> http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/userguide.html